# bash redirect in OSX doesn't work

Tags: macos, bash, redirect

I try to redirect output from a command in a terminal window in Max OSX (10.9.4) and get an error message. When I try this easy command:

```
ls > file_list.txt
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: file_list.txt: Operation not supported
```

Anybody an idea?

Thanks

Comment: What does `touch file_list.txt` say?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a permission or other file system related issue.

Comment: What does `ls -l file_list*` say? Maybe it is a device special file or a directory...

Answer (score 1):

This is the error you get if you try to create a file somewhere like `/dev`, which is the mount point for a special filesystem that doesn't (ordinarily) allow you to create files:

```
$ cd /dev
$ ls > file_list.txt
bash: file_list.txt: Permission denied
# Oops, we get permission denied before we even try to create the file.
$ sudo -s
Password:
# ls > file_list.txt
bash: file_list.txt: Operation not supported
```